# Is $\mathbb{Z}[x] / \langle (x^2 + 1)^2 \rangle$ isomorphic to a familiar ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}[x] / \langle (x^2 + 1)^2 \rangle$ was brought up in class today to contrast it with $\mathbb{Z}[x] / \langle x^2 + 1 \rangle$ after a discussion about adjoining elements to rings.  That is, the second quotient ring given here is of course isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.  We are adjoining $i$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ because $i$ satisfies $x^2 + 1 = 0$.  However, $i$ also satisfies $(x^2 + 1)^2 = 0$.  But surely $\mathbb{Z}[x] / \langle (x^2 + 1)^2 \rangle \not\cong \mathbb{Z}[x] / \langle x^2 + 1 \rangle$.  So is $\mathbb{Z}[x] / \langle (x^2 + 1)^2 \rangle$ isomorphic to some familiar ring?

I've tried to think of some homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ to other rings (e.g. $\mathbb{Z}[i] \times \mathbb{Z}[i]$) trying to get a kernel of $\langle (x^2 + 1)^2 \rangle$, but no luck.  Intuitively, it seems like we are "adjoining $i$ twice", to get a sort of $4$ dimensional structure, as compared to $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ which is like a $2$ dimensional structure.

EDIT:  A thought: perhaps the quotient is isomorphic to the Lipschitz quaternions?  I can't seem to prove this claim.

Comment: You are adjoining a nonzero square root of zero, which we could call $\tilde{0}$. Also, you are adjoining a number we could call $\tilde{\imath}$, which is a square root of $-1+\tilde{0}$.

Comment: Regarding your edit, I don't think you can find any square roots of $-1$ in your ring, or square roots of $0$ in the Lipschitz quaternions. Indeed the latter lacks zero divisors...and isn't even commutative!

Comment: @Kevin: How interesting! $(1/2) x (x^2 + 3)$ is a square root of $-1$, but alas that lies in the ring of fractions, not in the ring itself!

Comment: ... so we can get an alternate characterization of this ring as $$\mathbb{Z}[2i][x] / \langle x^2 - 2ix - 1 \rangle $$

Comment: Very related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414831/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ring

$$ \mathbb{Q}[x] / (x^2 + 1)^2 $$

is much easier to understand: with some work (e.g. Newton's method), we can discover that it contains a square root of unity:

$$ i := \frac{1}{2} x (x^2 + 3) $$

We can rewrite the ring as

$$ \mathbb{Q}(i)[x] / (x - i)^2 $$

This ring has an evident square root of zero (see the "dual numbers"), which I will call $e$. So this ring is simply

$$\mathbb{Q}[i, e]$$

The image of $x$ in this ring is $i+e$. We can verify that we get a homomorphism by expanding to check

$$ ((i+e)^2 + 1)^2 = 0$$

This ring can't be written as a product of rings: if we try to solve for idempotents

$$ (a + be)^2 = (a + be) $$

where $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}(i)$, the only solutions are $b=0$ and $a=0,1$.

---

Going back to the original ring, we can write

$$ \mathbb{Z}[x] / (x^2 + 1)^2 \cong \mathbb{Z}[i + e] $$

Of course, maybe this doesn't qualify as a 'familiar' ring....

Comment: (+1) Very cool.  That ring isn't familiar to me (I'm sure it is to someone), but it is still satisfying that there is a tangible ring to point to.  Thanks!

Comment: Ah, that's great.

Comment: Since $\mathbb{Q}(i,e)$ is not a field, I would choose another notation.

Comment: If $k$ is a commutative ring with $2 \in k^*$, then there is an isomorphism of $k$-algebras $k[x]/(x^2+1)^2 \cong k[i,e]/(i^2+1,e^2)$. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414831 for a proof.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks. I had typed $\mathbb{Q}[i,e]$, but accidentally went through the habit of changing the $[]$ to $()$. :(