# Understanding $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^{2}+1)^{2}$ contains…..

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This is a question about an answer to this question:

[Is $\mathbb{Z}[x] / \langle (x^2 + 1)^2 \rangle$ isomorphic to a familiar ring?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659096/is-mathbbzx-langle-x2-12-rangle-isomorphic-to-a-familiar-ring?rq=1)

Here the answer says that the ring $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^{2}+1)^{2}$ contains a square root of unity

$i:=\frac{1}{2}x(x^{2}+3)$

I'm not sure what that means. Also why was Newton's method mentioned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(\frac{1}{2}x(x^2+3))^2=\frac{1}{4}(x^2(x^4+6x^2+9)=\frac{1}{4}(-1(1-6+9))=-1$

Comment: you are welcome :) @user135520

Comment: why mister profull o took $x^2=-1$?

Comment: @UneFemmeDouce Who is mister profull o?

Comment: @awllower I am mister profullo...

Comment: Then why did you take $x^2=-1?$

Comment: @awllower : Original question is different from this edited question... please look at the original question..

Comment: I know that (Cf. my answer). But, after the question was changed, per chance you should edit the answer as well?

Comment: @awllower : I am a bit busy these days and could not edit that...

Answer (score 3):

$$x^2+3\equiv2\pmod{x^2+1},$$
so $$(x(x^2+3)/2)^2\equiv x^2\equiv-1\pmod{x^2+1},$$
and we can think of $x(x^2+3)/2$ as a square root of $-1.$
P.S. the element $x$ suffices for our purpose.
Hope this helps.
**Edit:**
I found that you wrote the question wrongly: the ring in question should be $\mathbb Q(x)/((x^2+1)^2).$
Then we shall see that $$(x^2+3)^2=x^4+6x^2+9\equiv 4x^2+8\pmod{(x^2+1)^2},$$
thus $$\frac{x^2(x^2+3)^2}{4}\equiv\frac{x^2(4x^2+8)}{4}=x^4+2x^2\equiv-1\pmod{(x^2+1)^2},$$ 
and this is why the element $x$ does not suffice in that linked answer.
Hope this clarifies some unclear points.

Comment: Thanks, I just saw this. The answer below showed why it was a square root of negative one. That's a good way to do it.

Comment: Your question body contains a typo, and I added an answer for the supposedly corrected question. And thanks for the appreciation.

Comment: Corrected the typo. Thanks