# The form of the subring generated by two subsets of a ring R

Tags: ring-theory

The form of  the subring generated by two subsets of a ring R:

> Let $R_i$ be a ring for each integer $i\in\Bbb Z$ and $R$ the direct product of $R_i$. I would like to know the definite form of the subring generated by $\oplus_{i\in \Bbb Z}R_i$ and $1_R$. Any help would be helpful.

[Original image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HOL4.png)

Comment: The notation $\oplus_i R_i$ is wrong. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345501

Comment: [Mariano's wisdom](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/416688/29335) applies well here, again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, the obvious idea works out well in this case.

Letting $S$ denote $\oplus_{i\in \Bbb Z}R_i$, we might speculate that everything in the subring generated by $S$ and $1_R$ looks like $T=\{x+n1_R\mid x\in S, n\in\Bbb Z\}$.

I don't think you'll have any trouble verifying that it's a ring: it's clearly closed under addition and multiplication, and has the same additive and multiplicative identities as the product ring above it. (Be sure to carry this verification out!)

Certainly the ring $T$ contains both $S$ and $1_R$, and conversely it's easy to see that any ring containing $S$ and $1_R$ must contain all the elements of $T$. So, $T$ is the ring generated by $S$ and $1_R$.

One last task: I mentioned that *the obvious idea works this time*. Suppose $R_1$ and $R_2$ are subrings of $R$, and try a similar idea to the one we used above with these rings. Can you see why the old idea doesn't directly work, and that something more complex is needed?